# Защищенный путь ReactRouterV6 и RTK Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Делаю доступ к Protected Route.
К апи  обращаюсь через РТК Query

```
 export const userAPI = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
      endpoints: (build) => ({
    getUser:build.query<IPersonInitial, void | null>({
      query: () => {
        return ({
          url: `${Endpoints.User.PROFILE}`,
      })},
      async onQueryStarted(args, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
          dispatch(setUser(data));
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      },
      providesTags: ['User'],      
    }),
  })
});
```

Для проверки авторизации написан кастомный хук

```
export const useAuthCheck = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const location = useLocation();
  const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || '/';
  const isUserSuccess = useAppSelector(selectIsUserSuccess);
  const isUserError = useAppSelector(selectIsUserError);
  const token = localStorage.getItem(StorageName.token);
  const isPreload = useAppSelector((state) => state.user.isPreloaded);
  const user = userAPI.endpoints.getUser.useQueryState().data;

  console.log({isPreload})
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (token && !Boolean(user)) {
      dispatch(userAPI.endpoints.getUser.initiate());    
    }
  },[])
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Boolean(user)) {
      dispatch(setPreloaded(false)); 
    } 
    
    if (!token) {
      dispatch(setPreloaded(false));
    }

    if (isUserError) {
      dispatch(setPreloaded(false)); 
    }   

  }, [isUserSuccess, isUserError, dispatch, token]);

  return { from, isPreload, user };
};
```

И проверяем есть ли у пользователя доступ к странице в элементе RequireAuth

```
export const RequireAuth = ({ allowedRoles }: IRequireAuth) => {
  const { isPreload, user, location } = useAuthCheck();

  return  isPreload 
  ? (<Loader />)
  : (
    allowedRoles.includes(user?.role!) 
      ? <Outlet />
      : Boolean(user)
        ? <Navigate 
            to='/unauthorized' 
            state={{ from: location}} 
            replace 
          />
        : <Navigate 
            to='/login' 
            state={{ from: location}}
            replace 
          />
  );
};
```

Проблема в том, что хотя у пользователя и есть доступ к элементу, срабатывает перенаправление на страницу Не авторизовано.